# probability for minimum of uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be iid uniform on the integers $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. Let $T_n=\min\{ n:X_n=X_m\mbox{ for some }m<n\}$.

1. Find $P(T_N>n)$
2. Find the limit as $N\rightarrow \infty$ of $P((T_N/\sqrt N)>x)$

I think I have number 1, but I am stuck on number 2. Use the density?

For number 1 I have:

$$P(T_N>n)= \frac{N}{N}  \frac{N-1}{N} \dots\frac{N-(n-1)}{N} = \prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{m}{N}\right).$$

Comment: What is your answer for number 1?

Comment: Do you mean that the $N$ random numbers,  $X_i$ are iid from the values ${1,2,...,N}$?

Comment: Hint: Use the formula you derived in (1) to solve part (2). Compute the limit $\log P(T_N/\sqrt{N}>x)$, then use continuity of $\log$ to finish. You'll encounter something like $\sum \log(1 - m/N)$. Use a Taylor expansion of $\log(1-y)$ at $y=0$. All terms in the Taylor expansion are negative, so convergence is absolute. Carefully bound the sums of second and higher order terms. The sum of all such terms goes to $0$. This leaves the sum of the first order terms, which you will see converges to $-\frac{1}{2}x^2$. So the answer is $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$.